# Magento 2: Products images are not showing on category page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-images, import-products

I have a huge catalog and imported images for them by csv file. Unfortunately images are not showing on category page but they are showing on view page.

I executed all the commands such as:

> php bin/magento cache:clean
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

But could not get images on category page. I also tried to execute:

> php bin/magento catalog:images:resize

I took almost 24 hours but this command did not finish successfully.

I observed that when i open that product from admin and just hit save without editing then image of that product shows on category page. Then i thought i should programmatically load each product and save but that idea did not work too.

Need help on it. Could any one provide a code of loading and saving a product just like admin do it or any other alternate?

Answer (score 0):

This was the bug from Magento version 2.1.6. In which Imported product's images not shown on frontend category page.

But Magento provided it's patch to resolve this bug.

So either you can use that bug or upgrade magento version to resolve this default bug.

Here is the ticket report: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/tech_bull_216-imageresize.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: You were right, my magento version was 2.1.6 but i upgraded to 2.1.9. But didn get images.

Comment: Download related patch from magento and apply it, I had same issue.

Comment: after installing that patch, images will be shown easily on category page? i mean there is no need to execute resize command or something else?

Comment: yes, Hope it helps you

Comment: it is not working.